# The statement: var = property(lambda self: object())

Tags: python, lambda

I'm addicted in reading libraries. I like the way their codes are structed and beautiful and most important: readable. I'm trying to learn by doing that. But, sometimes lines like this:

```
something = property(lambda self: object())
```

catch my eyes on!

I was inside `_socket.py` and this class:

```
class error(Exception):
    """ Base class for I/O related errors. """
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs): # real signature unknown
        pass

    @staticmethod # known case of __new__
    def __new__(S, *more): # real signature unknown; restored from __doc__
        """ T.__new__(S, ...) -> a new object with type S, a subtype of T """
        pass

    def __reduce__(self, *args, **kwargs): # real signature unknown
        pass

    def __str__(self): # real signature unknown; restored from __doc__
        """ x.__str__() <==> str(x) """
        pass

    characters_written = property(lambda self: object()) # default
    errno = property(lambda self: object()) # default
    filename = property(lambda self: object()) # default
    strerror = property(lambda self: object()) # default
```

The grant curiosity is over those 4 last lines containing `lambda` on them. The questions are: How that works? What are their meaning, their results? Can you show an example of that statement on a simple way?
Thanks for now!

Comment: `_socket.py`? I can't find it in either python2.7 nor python3.3 Did you mean `socket.py`? I don't see any definition of `error` in that file. The `_socket` module is implemented in C under `socketmodule.c`.

Comment: @Bakuriu, I don't know exactly, but I think the IDE might has something involved there. The IDE I'm actually using is PyCharm. The `socket.py` is importing `_socket.py` from this path: `/home/my_user/.PyCharm20/system/python_stubs/.../_socket.py` and just to avoid any guessing, I'm running Ubuntu.

Comment: Yes, that is *not* the real source code. That's only a stub that PyCharm uses to infer the types of the C extension module. The real source code is under `/Modules/socket.module.c` in the Python sources.

Answer (score 2):

First of all I would recommend reading [the python documentation about properties](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property). They are usually used to create fake attribute.

```
errno = property(lambda self: object()) # default
```

In your case, you only define a getter (no setter of deleter) for this attribute so `errno` is read only. And at each read it returns an brand new `object`. This is probably not very meaningful, but the rest of the library is probably expecting to have an `errno` variable.

Comment: thanks for the recommendation and for the effort in answering. I will for sure read it. Thanks!

Comment: one, potentially useful property of `object()` is that its equal to only itself; tests like `something.errno == SPECIAL_ERRNO_I_KNOW_ABOUT` is certainly false, when errno is a brand new instance of `object`

Answer (score 1):

[`property` is a built-in](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property). It's usually used as a decorator. That code is equivalent to this, which might look a bit more familiar:

```
class error(Exception):
    #...
    @property
    def characters_written(self):
        return object()

    @property
    def errno(self):
        return object()

    @property
    def filename(self):
        return object()

    @property
    def strerror(self):
        return object()
```

Still, it doesn't look particularly useful. It means that every time you try to retrieve any of those attributes on an instance of this error class you'll get back a new unique object instance.

Answer (score 0):

they look more like placeholders - perhaps unsupported implementations. they return useless objects. they seem to be suitable when you need a non-None value.